# More efficient alternative to For Each

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a faster and more efficient code than this one, as range will increase a lot over time, so I will need to substitute For Each.

The macro would look up the value "Monday" through each cell of a column and, if found, it would return the value "Substract" in the preceding cell in column A.

```
Sub ForEachTest()

Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("B3:B1000")

For Each cell In Rng

  If cell.Value = "Monday" Then
     cell.Offset(0, -1) = "Substract"
  End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: And when it is not `Monday`?

Comment: `Range("A3:A1000").Formula = "=IF(B3=""Monday"",""Substract"","""")"`?

Comment: Use formulas and not loops.

Comment: If you do not want to modify the cells that are **not** `Monday`, you can filter your range for `Monday` and then convert all visible cells in preceding column to `Subtract`

Comment: If the data is in a table then you can have the formula automatically added to new lines. It's magically delicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop within VBA rather than on the worksheet:

```
Sub faster()
    Dim arr()

    arr = Range("A3:B1000")

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 2) = "Monday" Then arr(i, 1) = "Substract"
    Next i

    Range("A3:B1000") = arr
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version addresses `BigBen`'s concern that column **B** should not be overwritten so as to preserve any formulas in that column.  Only column **A** is overwritten here:

```
Sub faster2()
    Dim arr(), brr()

    arr = Range("A3:A1000")
    brr = Range("B3:B1000")

    For i = LBound(brr, 1) To UBound(brr, 1)
        If brr(i, 1) = "Monday" Then arr(i, 1) = "Substract"
    Next i

    Range("A3:A1000") = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen   See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one question: What is the last "Range("A3:A1000") = arr" for? I do not understand its use  (as it is stated before), but if I remove it, the code does't  work!

Comment: @Jorge  That single statement fills the entire chunk of column **A** with the array values.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the loop by filtering your data and working with the resulting visible set of data.

*This will **only** modify the cells in `Column A` when `Column B = Monday`. All other cells remain as-is*

---

```
Sub Shelter_In_Place()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("A1:B" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Monday"
ws.Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "Subtract"

ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Evaluate

```
Sub Test()
With Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Value = Evaluate("IF(" & .Offset(, 1).Address & "=""Monday"",""Substract"","""")")
End With
End Sub
```